# Does this .htaccess rule internally redirect all traffic to a new directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm cleaning up some old code and came across a rule in a .htaccess that doesn't make sense to me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/listener/v2/bbin/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /listener/v3/v210_ui.php$1 [L]
```

This .htaccess file is located in `<docroot>/listener/v2/`. Unless I'm mistaken, the rule basically is stating that if the request is for a file in this directory, internally redirect it to `/listener/v3/v210_ui.php`.

My confusion stems from the fact that there are a lot of files in this directory. Am I missing something? Did the old developer just not clean up after themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close...

If the request is for a resource in `/listener/v2/bbin/` and has does not start with `/listener/v2/bbin/` in the URI redirect it to `/listener/v3/v210_ui.php` and append the URI.

Now why *you're* doing this I can't answer. Read up on [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Comment: So if there is only one root described in the apache config, it's safe to say that the files in that directory are never used, correct? (And assuming that other scripts don't call/include them)

Comment: I don't think you can draw that conclusion. The DocumentRoot doesn't have much to do with the above provided you can still access `/listener/v2/bbin/`.